# Openssh update promt that I need to bypass

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, openssh

I am writing a script that will get everything I need on a server installed and configured automatically with no user input, problem is that openssh asks about what I want to do with a file. tried force-confdef and confold, but those doesn't apply to openssh config I guess.

[image: picture of openssh config promt]

So I guess the question is, how can I get it to always choose default?
the marker already is on my right choice(default), it only need my input to enter, but i want to bypass the need for a human input.

This is what I thought would solve it:

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local

```
Dpkg::Options {" 
   "--force-confdef";"
   "--force-confold";"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a prompt from Debconf, the Debian configuration tool.  It has various frontends for acquiring information about what changes to make.  In your case, the way to get a noninteractive frontend is to set the environment `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` to `noninteractive`.

The noninteractive frontend does no prompting at all and so will always pick the default.  Note that for some packages, the default causes the package installation to abort, and so it won't be suitable for those cases.  However, in this particular case, it's probably going to work fine.